# Activity functions in Durable Function

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-durable-functions

I'm trying to learn converting an Azure Function to Durable Function. In the Azure Function, I have the code to get users for all the required AAD groups. Here is my code:

```
        IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient;
        GetUsersForEachGroup(IEnumerable<AzureADGroup> groups)
        {
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {           
                    var users = await GetUsersInGroupc(group);
            }
        }       

        GetUsersInGroup(Guid objectId)
        {
            var nonUserGraphObjects = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage members;            
            members = await graphServiceClient.Groups[objectId.ToString()].TransitiveMembers.Request()
                            .WithMaxRetry(MaxRetries)
                            .Select("id")
                            .GetAsync();
                var toReturn = new List<User>(ToUsers(members.CurrentPage, nonUserGraphObjects));
                while (members.NextPageRequest != null)
                {
                    members = await members.NextPageRequest.WithMaxRetry(MaxRetries).GetAsync();
                    toReturn.AddRange(ToUsers(members.CurrentPage, nonUserGraphObjects));
                }
                return toReturn;
          }

          ToUsers(IEnumerable<DirectoryObject> fromGraph, Dictionary<string, int> nonUserGraphObjects)
          {
            foreach (var directoryObj in fromGraph)
            {
                switch (directoryObj)
                {
                    case User user:
                        yield return new AzureADUser { ObjectId = Guid.Parse(user.Id) };
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (nonUserGraphObjects.TryGetValue(directoryObj.ODataType, out int count))
                            nonUserGraphObjects[directoryObj.ODataType] = count + 1;
                        else
                            nonUserGraphObjects[directoryObj.ODataType] = 1;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm thinking of adding an 1) Activity function to find out all the groups, 2) SubOrchestrator function 3) Activity function to get all users for each group. Is there a way I could add more Activity functions for the code GetUsersInGroup() for a better performance? Please let me know. Thank you!

```
[FunctionName("GetUsersInGroups")]
public static async Task GetUSersInGroups(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var groups = await context.CallActivityAsync<IEnumerable<AzureADGroup>>("GetGroups");
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string group in groups)
    {
        Task task = context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("GetUsers", group);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Is there a way I could add more Activity functions for the code GetUsersInGroup() for a better performance?` - Is `GetUsersInGroup` is not invoked via Activity function? Based on your posted code, one way to further optimize is  add parallelization (fan out/in - using tasks) while invoked `GetUsersInGroup` via `GetUsersForEachGroup`.

Comment: For example, is there a way to add an activity function to get users in each page (for each group) maybe?

Comment: What is `GetUsersForEachGroup`. Is it an orchestrator, sub-orchestrator or activity function? If sub-orchestrator or activity function you can convert it to fan-out/in pattern. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=csharp).